# Select dinâmico query botão submit e input

Tags: java, sql, jstl

Como fazer um select dinâmico em JSTL por uma JSP? Por exemplo, preencho CNPJ num `input id="cnpj"` e quando clico no botão submit ele pega esse valor do `input`, joga na SQL QUERY como parâmetro e executa na mesma página retornando pelo `C:out` o CNPJ e os outros campos da tabela.

[image: SS]

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar `JQuery` para criar um evento quando o usuário acionar o botão `BUSCAR` e na função `callback` referente ao evento você faz uma requisição ajax para buscas os registros no banco de dados e retorná-los em formato JSON.

[Clique aqui](https://jonsuh.com/blog/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return/) para ver essa abordagem utilizando PHP. Mas com JSP é o mesmo princípio.